# Installing Wamp on a Network Drive

Tags: wamp, wampserver

Ok, I have a quick question to ask all the veteran Wamp users on this board.

At work, we are currently working on a web application. We are trying to use Wamp to design everything, but we have a problem. All the computers right now have wamp installed to the default location (C:/wamp).

Our problem is, we all want to have access to the same MySQL database so we can edit it at the same time. Right now, only one person can edit it at a time to prevent losing the work of someone else.

When done, we just dump the mySQL folder onto a network drive so whoever wants to edit it next can take it and use it.

This isn't very time efficient, so we're wondering if its possible to install Wamp directly to a network drive in some way. We tried doing it just now but we can't get Wamp to start services.

So any type of advice will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think these two thing would help you :
1: install wamp in only one system then in apache configuration file listen to his lan ip in order to others can access it in this way you have just one database server
2: as you've installed wamp to all systems choose one system's database as main and in mysql configuration define a new server wich server's ip is that system's lan ip 
then users instead of using localhost for connecting to mysql will use that ip